# Similar to revshare - using paypal -

Tags: paypal, model

I am planning to launch a new advertising website where people can create an account, buy advertisements (banners, text, links, etc), see details on their account dashboard, etc. There will also be a section where the ads will be displayed and people who created accounts can consume and use the ads there.

It's a simple model that I have used before with paypal services for more than 8 months.

Now, the new thing that I want to introduce is something called "shares". What I mean by this is, that people can load money to buy that "shares" and get a pack of ads according to the amount they paid. (I could give more details if necessary).

Can I implement this model securely with PayPal?

Comment: Hi Amalia, I edited your question so that the most relevant details are clearer, but I think we still need more information about what you want PayPal to do. As it stands it's not really clear what kind of information you are seeking here.

Comment: At the end of the day, this can only be answered **officially** by PayPal -> [Acceptable Use Policy](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/acceptableuse-full) - technically, it's a payment flow. However, it will _likely_ (that's why it's best to ask for official answer/s) be based on business rules (that may have to be approved by Paypal)...